# Navigation drawer TextView Nullpointer exception

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a `TextView` in the navigation drawer of my app. When initially loading the relevant xml, the `TextView` (displaying users name and surname) runs fine without an error. However, after navigating to the next activity and returning immediately back to the previous activity the app crashes with a `NullPointerException`. Why does it load it successfully initially but crashes when navigating back? I have put in a null check but this just sets the `TextView`'s to blank but prevents the crashing.

My navigation header xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="117dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView15"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView40"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Part of the layout xml where i am referencing the navigation header:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/mydeals_seller_nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/seller_menu"/>
```

Referencing the `TextView` in the activity:

```
    docref = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    docref.collection("Users").whereEqualTo("uid", userid).get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { value->

            if (value != null ) {
                for (document in value!!) {

                    val user_name = document.getString("name")!!
                    val user_surname = document.getString("surname")!!

                    if(textView15 != null || textView40 != null){

                        menu_name = findViewById(R.id.textView15)!!
                        menu_surname = findViewById(R.id.textView40)!!

                        menu_name.setText("$user_name ")
                        menu_surname.setText(user_surname)
                    }


                }
            } else {

                Log.d("Firestore_error", "No Data")
            }

        }
```

Do I need a separate navigation header and `TextView` for each activity?

**Edit**
Testing this further on API 22, this issue doesnt present itself. Any suggestions?

Comment: Add exception call stack, please.

Comment: @art, https://ibb.co/xF0qtSm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of trial and error its seems like the error was a Firestore query issue. based on my query above i was using a loop where `userid` id matched the authenticated user. for some reason when moving between activities it resulted in a null pointer. i have no idea why but changing the query above to a single read as below fixed the issue:

```
docref = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
docref.collection("Users").document(userid).get()
    .addOnSuccessListener { value->

        if (value != null ) {

                val user_name = value.getString("name")!!
                val user_surname = value.getString("surname")!!

                if(textView15 != null || textView40 != null){

                    menu_name = findViewById(R.id.textView15)!!
                    menu_surname = findViewById(R.id.textView40)!!

                    menu_name.setText("$user_name ")
                    menu_surname.setText(user_surname)
                }

        } else {

            Log.d("Firestore_error", "No Data")
        }

    }
```

Just like that, no more `NullPointerException`. it would be great if a Firestore expert could explain why this was happening.

Answer (score 0):

```
  menu_name = findViewById(R.id.textView15)!!
                    menu_surname = findViewById(R.id.textView40)!!

                    menu_name.setText("$user_name ")
                    menu_surname.setText(user_surname)
```

Replace those lines with these:

```
val headerView = mydeals_seller_nav_view.getHeaderView(0)
val menu_name = headerView.textView15
val menu_surname = headerView.textView40

menu_name.setText("$user_name ")
menu_surname.setText(user_surname)
```

Comment: do i enter onResume() as an override function

Comment: i added it as an override function and it doesn't work.

Comment: @WaseemAhmed I edited my answer, try this and let me know if it works or not

Comment: this was suggested by another user and it crashed the app, it did not even load on first try.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the findViewById on the activity view you should call it on the header view like so:

```
docref.collection("Users").whereEqualTo("uid", userid).get()
    .addOnSuccessListener { value->
        if (value != null ) {
            for (document in value!!) {

                val user_name = document.getString("name")!!
                val user_surname = document.getString("surname")!!

                    // This gets the first header that is attached to the 
                    // navigation view
                    val header = mydeals_seller_nav_view.getHeaderView(0)

                    menu_name = header.findViewById(R.id.textView15)!!
                    menu_surname = header.findViewById(R.id.textView40)!!

                    menu_name.setText("$user_name ")
                    menu_surname.setText(user_surname)
                }


            }
        } else {

            Log.d("Firestore_error", "No Data")
        }

    }
```

Hope these fixies your issue

Comment: Hi @anes, this just causes the app to crash and doesn't even display the name on the first navigation to the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this...
You have to store that values in prefernces and set preferences values to textview or initialize firbase.instance in onResume() method.